# Do not reject mails with rspamd 1.7+

Tags: rspamd

I want to gradually fade out my spamassassin setup, replacing it with rspamd and I am currently one step away from activating the milter that will actually forward mails to my rspamd instance.

Before I do that I would like to test if rspamd is accidentally being too conservative or too lax. I have modified `spam_header` in `local.d/worker-proxy.inc` so it wont override spamassassins output and I upped the `reject` actions threshold to 30. While this should do it in theory, it would be nice to never reject any mails, just to be on the safe side.

Is there a way to instruct rspamd to never reject mails and only set the spam headers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `reject` to `null` in `/etc/rspamd/override.d/actions.conf`:

```
# /etc/rspamd/override.d/actions.conf
reject = null;
```

On older versions of `rspamd` this had to be done in `/etc/rspamd/override.d/metrics.conf` and before version `1.6` there was `spamd_never_reject`

The current way to achieve this can be found [here](https://rspamd.com/doc/tutorials/writing_rules.html).